# Enable Javascript on B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Javascript is disabled on the Client Side, even though i have added below as per documentation.

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
   <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
</RelyingParty>
```

When i try to upload the Custom Policy, i get an error - "Please use page contract in content definitions when enabling JavaScript." Cannot find anything related to this error in documentation.

Tried to add metadata to content definitions, using datauri -

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">  
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
  ...
 </ContentDefinition>
```

Expect javascript to work on client side login pages

Answer (score 7):

If you are still facing the errors, then replace the `DataUri` tag from

`<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:idpselection:1.2.0</DataUri>` to `<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0</DataUri>`

for the `ContentDefinition` `api.idpselections` and `api.idpselections.signup`.

Comment: Not just the 3 DataUri you listed, ALL of them in use ... ex i missed one: `unifiedssp` and threw same error as OP mentioned

Answer (score 3):

I facing the same problem, to correct I follow this steps(for custom policies):

First: in _Base.Xml go to ContentDefinitions and find for DataUri, change all old uris to new like this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout

Second:  ensure that you have the word "contract" between your elements and your page identifier, example: change this
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:globalexception:1.2.0
for this
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0

Third: in your specific Custom Policie, find for RelyingParty and add the ScriptExecution element to the UserJourneyBehaviors element of RelyingParty

some like this

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
</RelyingParty>
```

Fourth: upload the base.xml, upload your custom policy.xml and enjoy!

greetings from Brasil.

Comment: This helped me, and also considering this page:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-azure-active-directory-b2c-supports-javascript-with-page-contract-in-custom-policies/

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still facing error, then you should replace ***all*** the data URIs in your content definitions with the one's defined in the below url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout

Use the **new data URI** instead of **Old** one everywhere in your policy and this will fix the issue. Mine was fixed using the same approach. Not only that but the Microsoft documentation clearly states that "*If you intend to use JavaScript, you need to define a page layout version with page contract version for **all** of the content definitions in your custom policy*".

Refer the url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me Only when I update all ***ContentDefinition*** with ***contract*** Like, It's take my time

SignUpOrSignin.xml

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
  <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml / TrustFrameworkBase.xml

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.appfactor.registration">
    <LoadUri>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdzzaman/dev-info/master/az/selfasserted-appfactor-registration.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdzzaman/dev-info/master/az/selfasserted-appfactor-registration.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.6</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">App Factor</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>


 <ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
    <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.1</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>

  <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.4</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

...
All

Answer (score 0):

I observed two issues despite having all the settings of AAD B2C policies correct. First issue was that browser was caching old html and I needed to to reload with clearing the cache. Another issue was that if I followed recommendation from AAD B2C documentation to palce the script into header, it wasn't executing. I moved it to the body element and it worked.